# Save different sized string lists in csv

Tags: python

I have the follwing lists an I want to store them in the `csv` example bellow. Can you help? I have seen relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file) but the obtained `csv` is not what I want. I past the output since now accoring to the afforementioned post.

```
list1 = ['str1', 'str2','str3']
list2 = ['str1']
list3 = ['str1', 'str2']
lists.append(list1)
lists.append(list2)
lists.append(list3) 

for l in lists:
   '''save each list in a csv row where each element of the 
      list will be stored in separete cell.'''
```

**CSV example**:

```
     cell1 cell2 cell3 
row1  str1 str2 str3
row2  str1
row3  str1 str2
```

**CSV undesired(place all strings in the first cell)**:

```
      cell1          cell2 cell3 
row1  str1 str2 str3
row2  str1
row3  str1 str2
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on: "For each row of the csv the strings of the specific list will be stored in a cell", please? Perhaps give an example, because it is quite confusing - as read from what you have, it seems as though you've mistaken cells with rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library:

```
import csv

with open('your_file.csv', 'wb') as csv_file: 
   csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
   for l in lists:
        csv_writer.writerow(l)
```

Comment: I think instead of `reader` writter is needed. Also all the strings from all the lists are stored in the first collumn.

Comment: Yes writer indeed. Updated the answer. By default, it separates string by a comma ",", the strings are not in the same column. You can set another delimiter if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Or just this way :

```
file = open("newfile.csv", "w")
sep = ";"    # your favorite separator
for l in list :
    for e in l :
        file.write (e + sep)
    file.write ("\n")
```