# how to create a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm not sure how to create csv file, I then also want to learn how to save data on it. I have variables I want to enter in python, and I want to transfer them to excel. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this problem!

```
import csv


def nasif():
    myfile= open("MARIA.csv","wb")
    wr=csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    mylist=["Name","address","telephone"]
    wr.writerow(mylist)



def maria():
    c = csv.writer(open("MARIA.csv","rb"))

    c.writerow(["Name","address","telephone"])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Don't forget to close your file and check your open modes, but what's your problem exactly ?

Comment: use python `xlrd` module for excel format.

Comment: Unclear to me. Are you aware the 'r' in "rb" stands for *read*?