# Export default value in 1 row

Tags: python

I have a method that export to csv. and I have a list with default values. The problem is that the default values go into one column, and I want them to go into a single row. [image]

```
list = ['test1', 'test2, 'test3']
```

Comment: Hi, please look at this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
l = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(l)
```

You'd better not use list as a variable name, since it collides with python's internal list function.