# Writing a nested list into CSV (Python)

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv

I have a list that looks like this:

```
hello = [(('case', 'iphone'), 91524), (('adapter', 'iphone'), 12233), (('battery', 'smartphone'), 88884)]
```

And I am simply trying to write it to a csv file, looking like this:

```
keyword 1           keyword 2          frequency
case                iphone             91524
adapter             iphone             12233
battery             smartphone         88884
```

I can't figure my way around it. I couldn't transform the list into a DataFrame, either. I tried to apply some code suggested here [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file) without any success.

Comment: `writer.writerows((a,b,c) for (a, b), c in data)`

Comment: Also checkout pandas if you're going to be working with that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas is convenient for this:

```
import pandas as pd

hello = [(('case', 'iphone'), 91524), (('adapter', 'iphone'), 12233), (('battery', 'smartphone'), 88884)]

df = pd.DataFrame([[i[0][0], i[0][1], i[1]] for i in hello],
                  columns=['keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'frequency'])

#   keyword 1   keyword 2  frequency
# 0      case      iphone      91524
# 1   adapter      iphone      12233
# 2   battery  smartphone      88884

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

If in `pandas`

```
s=pd.Series(dict(hello)).reset_index()
s.columns=['keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'frequency']
s
Out[1012]: 
  keyword 1   keyword 2  frequency
0   adapter      iphone      12233
1   battery  smartphone      88884
2      case      iphone      91524
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking:

```
import csv
hello = [(('case', 'iphone'), 91524), (('adapter', 'iphone'), 12233), (('battery', 'smartphone'), 88884)]
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
   write = csv.writer(f)
   write.writerows([['keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'frequency']]+[[a, b, c] for [a, b], c in hello])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using `pandas`, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
hello = [(('case', 'iphone'), 91524), (('adapter', 'iphone'), 12233), (('battery', 'smartphone'), 88884)]

df=pd.DataFrame({'keyword1':[i[0][0] for i in hello], 'keyword2':[i[0][1] for i in hello], 'frequency':[i[1] for i in hello]})

df[['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'frequency']].to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly good solution to me.  Looping over `hello` three times seems unnecessary.