# Writing nested list into csv by column

Tags: python, list, csv, writefile

I have a list of lists looks like this:

```
signals_list = [ [1,4,7..... 5,7],[4,-7,1....-5,-8,4],.....]
```

I want to write these inner lists **column wise** in a csv file. **I have 176 inner lists and 176 column needs to be made. Every inner list has almost 39400 instants.**

Csv should look like this:

[image]

> What i have tried:
>
> [writing nested list into csv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074599/writing-a-nested-list-into-csv-python)
>
> [write python list of list into csv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

**What i have done**

```
# GETTING ALL THE WAV FILES FROM DIRECTORY AND CONVERTING INTO NUMPY ARRAY
path = "C:/Users/Marwat/.spyder-py3/FYP/input/set_a/"
files = os.listdir(path)
print(len(files))
signals_list = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.wav')):
    sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(filename)
    signals = [np.array(data,dtype=int)]
    signals_list.append(signals)


# WRITING SIGNALS TO CSV FILE
d = [signals_list]
col_name = 1
transposed_signals = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '')
with open('C:/Users/Marwat/.spyder-py3/FYP/input/numbers.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      wr.writerow('sound_'+ str(col_name))
      wr.writerows(transposed_signals)
      col_name +=1
myfile.close()
```

> OUTPUT
>
> [image: Output for my above code]

**Any help will be highly appreciated**

Comment: Can you say of the things you've tried,which gets you _closest_ to your goal, and how it differs from your desired output?  Also, I'm not understanding your desired translation to CSV: for example you have  a -3 in your list, but it doesn't show anywhere in your CSV.

Comment: i have edit my questions and -3 was dummy value just to show my requirement

Comment: ATTENTION: THIS CODE WORKS PERFECTLY FOR ME. THANKS TO ALL OF YOU.                                                                                                                           'list = []
for i in range(len(signals_list)):
    list.append(('sound'+str(i+1)))   
    
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list)
for i in range(len(signals_list)):
    df[list[i]] = pd.Series(signals_list[i][0])
df.to_csv('PATH/TO/FILE.csv',sep=',',index=False) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. The two places you are running into problems are:

1) Sticking `signals_list` inside an outer list. Pass `signals_list` directly to `zip_longest` and you should be set there:

```
transposed_signals = list(zip_longest(*signals_list, fill_value = ''))
```

2) Writing the header row. First, you need to write all columns in that row (you're just writing one). Also, `writerow()` expects an iterable, which is why, when you pass a string, you get one character per column. Try this instead, and leave out `col_name`:

```
wr.writerow(('sound_' + str(i + 1) for i in range(len(transposed_signals))))
```

Putting it all together (just the second part), you should have:

```
transposed_signals = list(zip_longest(*signals_list, fillvalue=''))
with open('C:/Users/Marwat/.spyder-py3/FYP/input/numbers.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(('sound_' + str(i + 1) for i in range(len(transposed_signals))))
    wr.writerows(transposed_signals)

# Calling myfile.close() isn't necessary since `with` does that automatically upon exiting that scope.
```

Comment: i didn't try your code but it seems correct to me. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your list in a numpy array and transpose it

```
array = np.array(signals_list)
array = array.T
```

Then use pandas to create a DataFrame and store it as csv

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df.to_csv('my_signals.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `zip()`

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) transposes a list*, so rows become columns and columns become rows. Based on the second link, you can do:

```py
import csv

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(*a))
```

If this doesn't work for you, please tell me how it doesn't work so I can fix it.

*It doesn't *actually* transpose a list, it "aggregates elements from each of the iterables", which in this case is essentially the same.

Comment: if i use writer.writerows(zip(a)) it has same output as mine, you can check my question i have edit it.

Comment: You need to use `writer.writerows(zip(*a))`, with the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dataframe`, transpose it then set the headers in place and export it to a csv file

```
import pandas as pd    
signals_list =  [[1,4,7],[4,-7,1],[1,9,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data =signals_list ,columns=["a","b","c"]).T
df.columns = df.index.tolist()
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```