# Writing Big list to dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a Big size `list` to dataframe. 
Length of the list `len(rows_list)` is `15347782` which is pretty big. 
Worked well with lesser size of list using this :

`df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)`

But this breaks because of `memory error` when I try to convert this size of list into dataframe.

Is there any way of implementing `chunksize` while writing it into dataframe? Like we do while writing big size file to csv or reading a big size file from csv.

Or there is any other smooth way for this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2 questions: (1) Are you tied to `pandas`? [in general, `pandas` is best used for in-memory manipulation], (2) what are the contest of the `list` [if strings, are there many *repeated* strings?] ?

Comment: Hi @jpp thanks for your reply. will it not be possible in pandas because of this size? and my `list` consists of numbers strings everything

Comment: `pandas` has a significant overhead relative to native Python types. So, yes, it is likely size-linked. In addition, you are holding 2 copies of data when you build the dataframe (the list itself, and the `numpy` representation in the dataframe). That's double the memory requirement. If you need to do this efficiently, and this is your only task, don't use `pandas`.

Comment: okay, are you aware of any other alternatives?

Comment: I need to put my list to dataframe and from dataframe to csv file

Comment: Yup, check this out: [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Explain *why* you need to use a dataframe.

Comment: @jpp- your link worked beautifully for me. thanks :)