# How can i add my data properly in csv format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My code to write my data in a .txt file:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    id = 1
    for line in value:
        line = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9-,]+', '', str(line))
        ymax, xmax, xmin, ymin=line.split(',')
        f.write(('{{\'yMax\': u\'{}\', \'xMax\': u\'{}\', \'xMin\': u\'{}\',\'yMin\': u\'{}\', \'id\': \'{}\', \'name\': \'\'}}'.format(ymax, xmax, xmin, ymin,id)))
        id = id + 1
```

outcome :

```
{'yMax': u'156', 'xMax': u'4802', 'xMin': u'4770','yMin': u'141', 'id': '1', 'name': ''}
{'yMax': u'157', 'xMax': u'4895', 'xMin': u'4810','yMin': u'141', 'id': '2', 'name': ''}
```

However i want my data in a table like format of .csv:

```
image     id    name    xMin    xMax    yMin    yMax
1-0.png   1             4770    4802    141     156
1-0.png   2             4810    4895    141     157
```

How can i adjust my code to go from the .txt format i already have to the .csv format i want? The excess column which is image is simply the filename of the txt but .png instead of txt so easy enough using `re` i can adjust later my main issue is the table shape.

Comment: there is a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv). i suggest you use it.

Comment: Oh i'm new to python, mind adding a full answer bellow so i can accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help. use `csv.DictWriter`

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=['yMax', 'xMax', 'xMin', 'yMin', 'id', 'name'])      #Tab seperated
    writer.writeheader()    #Add header
    for i, line in enumerate(value, 1):             #enumerate to get id
        line = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9-,]+', '', str(line))
        ymax, xmax, xmin, ymin=line.split(',')
        d = {'yMax': ymax,'xMax': xmax, 'xMin': xmin,'yMin': ymin, 'id': i, 'name': ''}
        writer.writerow(d)
```

**Note**: This is sample code.

Comment: got this error `    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter='\t')  # Tab seperated
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fieldnames'`

Comment: add the `fieldnames`. Updated snippet.

Comment: I updated then got this error `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'x', 'M', 'a', 'x'`

Comment: Sorry use `writerow`

Comment: That's because you must have set `file_path` with a `.txt` extension . Replace that to `.csv`