# How to write a list to CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have been trying to put list in to csv file but it's not taking the whole word as input but as a letter and inserting every letter in separate cell

```
import csv

data = {}

with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as fp:

    a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
    data = ['sales','tax']
    a.writerows(data)
```

The output is:

```
s       a    l  e   s
t   a   x
```

with each letter in separate cell

I need output like:

```
Sales
Tax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Do you want `sales` and `tax` on a line each or as columns on the same line?

Answer (score 5):

`.writerows()` (plural) expects a list of lists (or more accurately, an iterable of iterables) representing multiple rows.  Use `.writerow()` (singular) to pass a single list representing one row.

To explain your current output...since a string is iterable, a list of strings looks like an iterable of iterables, but each column ends up being a single letter when used with `.writerows()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = ['sales','tax']
a.writerows(data)
```

Is treating `data` as a list of rows, not as a single row. Try

```
data = [['sales', 'tax']]
a.writerows(data)
```

Where `data` is a list containing a single list (row).

Or

```
data = ['sales', 'tax']
a.writerow(data) # note row not rows
```

to write a single row.