# How to write comma seperated values into a single csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a csv file with a single column, where each row is a list of values seperated by ',' or ';', how can I do that?

Here is an example:
the data [['s', [1, 2, 3]], ['a', [4, 5, 6]]]

I want a csv like this

file data

s   1;2;3

a   4,5;6

with only two column

Comment: use `csv` module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: well it's not gonna be a single column !

Comment: really? can I do that with pandas?

Comment: The number of columns depends on the separater you select when reading the file back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily with the [join() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators).

Example:

```
data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
with open("my_file.txt", "w") as f:
  for line in data:
    f.write(",".join(str(cell) for cell in line) + "\n")
```

Output (`cat my_file.txt`):

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Feel free to comment if something is unclear.

Comment: hi, I tried this method. But is it the same to save data as int and save data as str?

Comment: I think whether you save it as int or str, you will read it as str, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. You can see a text file as a big string if it helps. I used `str()` here because `join()` requires a string. But when you'll read data from this file, it won't change anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not gonna be a single column, there are lots of ways to do this

you can use `pandas` `DataFrame` to write your list into a `csv` file, write your list in a `dict`, then use the `dict` to create the `csv` file easily

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'s': [1, 2, 3], 'a':[4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv ('output.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

`output.csv` would be like :

[image]