# How to append a list as row in csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I intend to append following list into a csv file so that it appears in a single row but my code isn't working. I'm a beginner in python. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank You.

`list_one = ['apple','ball','cat','dog']`

I tried following code:

```
import csv

list = ['apple','cat','dog']

with open('document.csv','a') as fd:
  fd.writerows(list)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

list = ['apple','cat','dog']

with open('document.csv','a') as fd:
  write = csv.writer(fd)   
  write.writerow(list)
```