# List of lists to csv with commas to separate fields and newlines to separate rows

Tags: python, list, csv

I tried doing what was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file) but this does not seem to give me the right output. Instead the csv file seems to interpret each sublist as a field. Instead each value in a sublist should be a field for one row.

**An example**

Dummy data:

`test=[['a','1','!'],['b','2','?']]`

My current code:

```
with open('./csv_files/CtMLI.csv', 'w', newline="\n") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(test)
```

Output of code (CtMLI.csv):

```
"['a', '1', '!']","['b', '2', '?']"
```

Desired output (of CtMLI.csv):

```
'a', '1', '!'
'b', '2', '?'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `writerows` instead of `writerow`.

```py
import csv

test=[['a','1','!'],['b','2','?']]

with open('./csv_files/CtMLI.csv', 'w', newline="\n") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerows(test)
```