# Converting list of lists into tuple and write to csv

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists.

```
lst = [['cp1', 'cp2'], ['ac1', 'ac2'], ['12/12/2020', '12/12/2020']]
```

i want to convert this into dict or tuple and write to csv as per below format.

```
cp1;ac1;12/12/2020

cp2,ac2,12/12/2020
```

but the length of lst is not fixed it is dynamic (here it is 3 lists inside  but can it can be N) . However lists in lst will have same number of element (in above example length is 2 ) .

Any pointer will be helpfull .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip and csv module:

```
data  = [['cp1', 'cp2'], ['ac1', 'ac2'], ['12/12/2020', '12/12/2020']]

import csv

with open ("test.csv","w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(*data))


with open("test.csv") as r:
    print(r.read())
```

Output:

```
cp1,ac1,12/12/2020
cp2,ac2,12/12/2020
```

This will work as long as you make sure your inner lists all have the same lenght. If one is shorter *all* lists will be shortened to that lenght. Use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to avoid that shortening.

See [Writing a Python list of lists to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file) if your lists are already formatted correctly and do not need to be transposed before writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) builtin:

```
>>> list(zip(*lst))
[('cp1', 'ac1', '12/12/2020'), ('cp2', 'ac2', '12/12/2020')]
```

This will work with lists of any size.

Comment: Thanks  for help , I really appreciate it !!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you need:

```
lst = [['cp1', 'cp2'], ['ac1', 'ac2'], ['12/12/2020', '12/12/2020']]
output = ""
for inner_list in lst:
    output += inner_list[0] + ";"
output = output[:len(output) - 2] + "\n\n"
for inner_list in lst:
    output += inner_list[1] + ";"
output = output[:len(output) - 2]
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks @cohen for help . This works but unfortunately I can mark only one. This works too .

Comment: Fair enough, no worries