# How to concatenate string to specific format using Python?

Tags: python, excel

Good morning,

I am a new python user and I am trying to replicate the following excel function in python:

```
=concatenate(left(H2,search(" ",H2,1)-1),if(LEN(right(H2,LEN(H2)-search(" ",H2,1)))=2,"00",if(LEN(right(H2,LEN(H2)-search(" ",H2,1)))=3,"0","")),right(H2,LEN(H2)-search(" ",H2,1)),"-KG")
```

I am trying to convert Highways into a format my computer program(arcgis) reads, basically turn my csv column format from:

[image]

the right column into the left column, so basically keep the two letter in the front (ex. US,FM,SL, CR) adding zeros in front making it a 4 digit highway always and adding "-KG" to the end.

thanks

Comment: Are you using pandas?  Please show some sample data, and what code you've tried so far  so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function converts the old highway format into your desired format:

```
def convert(highway):
    split = highway.split()
    prefix = split[0]
    number = split[1]
    return prefix + (4 - len(number))*"0" + number + "-KG"
```

If you're working with a pandas dataframe, this converts your whole column:

```
import pandas as pd

highways = ["US 90", "FM 1436", "SL 305", "US 277", "FM 1689", "SL 480"]

df = pd.DataFrame(highways, columns=["Highways"])
df["Highways"] = df["Highways"].transform(convert, axis=0)

print(df)
```

Out:

```
    Highways
0  US0090-KG
1  FM1436-KG
2  SL0305-KG
3  US0277-KG
4  FM1689-KG
5  SL0480-KG
```

Or if you're using a list:

```
highways = ["US 90", "FM 1436", "SL 305", "US 277", "FM 1689", "SL 480"]
new_highways = [convert(highway) for highway in highways]
print(new_highways)
```

Out:

```
['US0090-KG', 'FM1436-KG', 'SL0305-KG', 'US0277-KG', 'FM1689-KG', 'SL0480-KG']
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Python lists such as

```
arr = ['US 90', 'FM 1436', 'SL 305', 'US 277', 'FM 1589', 'SL 480']
```

do

```
result = [f'{s}{n:0>4}-KG' for s, n in map(str.split, arr)]
```

which gives

```
['US0090-KG', 'FM1436-KG', 'SL0305-KG', 'US0277-KG', 'FM1589-KG', 'SL0480-KG']
```

Answer (score 1):

This would look something like:

```
import csv

with open("yourfile.csv") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=" ")
    output = [[' '.join(row),f'{row[0]}{row[1].zfill(4)}-KG'] for row in reader]

print(output)
```

---

```
[['US 50', 'US0050-KG'], ['CA 987', 'CA0987-KG'], ['IL 4', 'IL0004-KG']]
```

The `zfill()` function will left pad a string with the `0` character to make the string the length of the argument (`4` in this case)

If you are wanting to write that list of lists back out, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14037564/2221001)

Comment: `{row[1].zfill(4)}` in an fstring is more succinctly written `{row[1]:0>4}` but perhaps `.zfill()` is clearer.

Comment: Totally agree. As usual there are a bunch of ways to skin this cat. I already dumped list comprehension in here so tossing in `{row[1]:0>4}` syntax isn't pushing it too far IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the string format instead of zfill:
Here's an example it's not for csv but in arcgis I think you wanted to use it in the atributte calculator.

```
List= ['US 90','FM 1436','SL 305']

for elem in List:
    Splited = str(elem).split(' ')
    Concatenated_elem = str(Splited[0]) + f'{int(Splited[1]):04d}' +'-KG'
    print(Concatenated_elem)
```

The result in this case is a print:

```
US0090-KG
FM1436-KG
SL0305-KG
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: `{int(Splited[1]):04d}` can be done without conversion to integer `{Splited[1]:0>4}` where `0` is the pad character, `>` means justify right, and `4` specifies the width.

Comment: Apparently you can not:
`Concatenated_elem = str(Splited[0]) + f'{Splited[1]:04d}'`
`ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'`

Comment: You used `04d`, but should have used `0>4`

Comment: The `Concatenated_elem` is unnecessarily complicated, the reformatting can be done with a single f-string:  `f"{Splited[0]}{Splited[1]:0>4}-KG"`